# Python: How to freeze/dissable some items in wxCheckListBox?

Tags: python, wxpython, freeze, checklistbox

I am trying to implement a `wx.CheckListBox` in Python in which I want to have some items in the list always get checked. I have tried to use `SetCheckedStrings(stringList)` on the event `wx.EVT_CHECKLISTBOX`. However I got the opposite result, when I unchecked one item in the `stringList`, it is unchecked; when I click on that again to check it, and it would never let me check again.

Can anyone give me some hint to keep some items in `wx.CheckListBox` always get checked or make those uncheckable?

Answer (score 0):

If event steps in your way, you can always disable it for a while using `self.box.Unbind(wx.EVT_CHECKLISTBOX)`. However this sample works for me even without unbinding:

```
import wx

CHOICES = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
ALWAYS_ON = ["One", "Three"]

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.box = wx.CheckListBox(self.panel, choices=CHOICES)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.box)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)  
        self.Show()

        self.box.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKLISTBOX, self.OnCheckBoxList)
        self.box.SetCheckedStrings(ALWAYS_ON)

    def OnCheckBoxList(self, e):       
        index = e.GetSelection()
        label = self.box.GetString(index)
        if label in ALWAYS_ON:
            self.box.Check(index)           

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I tried your code on my computer: It appeared with box "One" and "three" were checked. When I click on those, they were unchecked, and I couldn't check those boxes again. I am running Mac OSX 10.8.2, python 2.7.2. When I tried your program on another computer running Linux, it worked well. I think Mac has problem with this. Do you have any idea to bypass this?

Comment: Try adding a print statement to the event handler. Is the event handler called only once?

Comment: Also your Mac system behaves as if there was line like this `self.box.Check(index, False)`. Try using that instead of `self.box.Check(index)`. You may also try `self.box.Check(index, True)`. Maybe there is a bug which has wrong implicit value for the second parameter.

Comment: I've added print in event handler, it is called once only whenever I check/uncheck an item. When I tried self.box.Check(index,False): the first click on item "One", it is unchecked, from the second clicked, it is checked and can't unchecked again. When I tried self.box.Check(index,True): when click on item "One", it is unchecked can't checked again.

Comment: So you have to play with `self.box.Check(index, False)` and `self.box.Check(index, True)` to get the desired behavior. Unfortunately I do not have Mac OS to try it. You may also ask on the wxPython mailing list.